# python method: append returns an empty list in subclass of an abstract class

Tags: python-3.x, list, append, abstract-methods

I am trying to get familiar with abstract classes, but cannot figure out how I can append to an empty list in the class. this is how the directory i am working in looks like:

```
 my_dir
  |__data
  |    |__colors
  |    |    |__light_colors.csv
  |    |    |__dark_colors.csv
  |    |    |__cold_colors.json
  |    |__ages
  |__code
       |__data_reader.py
       |__config.py
```

in my config file i have:

```
import os

REPO_ROOT_DIRECTORY = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
colors_DATA_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(REPO_ROOT_DIRECTORY, "data")
```

and in my data_reader.py file i have the following code, which is an abstract class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from config import colors_DATA_DIRECTORY
import os

class PathReader(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def read_data_type(self): pass
    
class colorReader(PathReader):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path_to_types = os.path.join(colors_DATA_DIRECTORY, 'colors')
        self.colors= []
        # print(self.colors)-->empty

    def read_data_type(self):
        for files in os.listdir(self.path_to_types):
            all_colors = os.path.join(self.path_to_types, files)
            self.colors.append(all_colors)
            # print(all_colors) --> prints the .csv and .json files and their path
            # print(files) --> prints the .csv and .json files

 g= colorReader()
 print(g.read_data_type())
```

i am not sure which part of the method is wrong, so that the append does not work. i tried to print out elements in the for loop and everything seems fine, but when i print the self.colors list, it is empty.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the issue is the `self.colors` in `__init__` is empty? It should be since nothing would have been run by that point to populate it. If you're saying it's empty after running `read_data_type`, `os.listdir(self.path_to_types)` must be empty. Also note that `read_data_type` doesn't return anything, so `print(g.read_data_type())` won't print anything meaningful.

Comment: thank you for your reply. the os.listdir(self.path_to_types) is not empty. that is why i do not know where this problem is coming from

Comment: You need to clarify the problem first, since it's not very clear what's being asked. What exact `print` is showing an empty list?

Comment: the prints are all commented in the code above, the print(self.colors) is an empty list. the rest of the prints are just to show that the for loop is fine

Comment: As mentioned above, it doesn't make any sense for the `print` in `__init__` to return a non-empty list; it must be empty. You never put anything in the list before that `print` runs. You need to `print` after that method runs, not before.

Comment: yes, you are right. but even when i print it after the method runs, it is still empty.

Comment: If `self.colors` is empty after `read_data_type` runs, that means `os.listdir(self.path_to_types)` must be empty. I cannot see any other explanation. Make sure the test you did that showed it as non-empty is the same as your actual runs.